# Heroku Application Error (Ruby 2.2.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, gemfile

I have a Rails app and I try to push it to Heroku. After I pushed it to Heroku, I get Application Error message.

When I run `heroku logs -n 300`, I get [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/56a2871b4de3576e2417) (sorry for pasting the logs in Gist. StackOverflow not allowing me to post >30K characters question).

This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Twitter Bootstrap
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.2.0.0'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Devise for user auth
gem 'devise'

# CanCanCan for user roles
gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.10'

# Gravatar
gem 'gravatar_image_tag'

# Font Awesome
gem 'font-awesome-sass'

group :development, :test do
  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3'

  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end

ruby "2.2.2"
```

I thought that the error is because I'm not running `rake db:migrate` on Heroku. But, after I run `heroku run rake db:migrate`, the error is still same.

What should I do?

Note: This app runs well on my localhost.

Comment: You need to figure out why your getting this error - /app/app/controllers/Users/confirmations_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Users (NameError)

Comment: Thanks bro. Just found the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting a `uninitialized constant Users (NameError)` error in the `app/controllers/Users/confirmations_controller.rb` file, line 1. Probably you're trying to use an `User` class, in the singular, and just mistyped it.

Comment: Thanks bro. Just found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I moved all my Users controllers inside /controllers/ folder.

```
app/controllers/Users/*_controller.rb
```

into

```
app/controllers/
```

...and delete the Users folder.